# Adding searchbar in ionic android app

Tags: android, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I am working on a simple android application with ionic framework. I have bunch of different json files showing list on different views. I got stuck in search functionality.. how "$scope.data" will work for different jsons? as I have seen in examples over internet everyone has provided json data inline in $scope.data.
Quick pointers would be really helpful. Many thanks.